# Instagram private API error with PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api, pythonanywhere

When I enter `python /home/pyinstastories.py --username USERNAME --password PASSWORD --download USER` in my terminal it works great. I want to use it with PythonAnywhere.com but it's not working. I came across this error twice, the error is printed below.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
[I] PYINSTASTORIES (SCRIPT V2.6 - PYTHON V2.7.12) - 01:54:38 PM
----------------------------------------------------------------------
[W] Unable to find auth cookie file: credentials.json (creating a new one...)
[E] Client Error: {"status": "fail", "message": "challenge_required", "error_type": "checkpoint_challenge_required", "challenge": {"api_path": "/challenge/15299529987
/hparGkFgqV/", "native_flow": true, "url": "https://i.instagram.com/challenge/15299529987/hparGkFgqV/", "lock": true, "flow_render_type": 0, "logout": false, "hide_we
bview_header": true}}
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is this a VPN / IP issue? Is Instagram checking PythonAnywhere's IP address and not submitting my request? Not sure what it means.

Comment: How are you running the command? The way you quoted it here is unlikely to run on PythonAnywhere. Moreover free accounts on PythonAnywhere have restricted access to the Internet with the possibility to connect only with the whitelisted public APIs. So if you have a free account this could also be a problem.

Comment: I've had once a smilliar issue, problem was indeed with my IP, i had first login normally into instagram and confirm the Login via a Link send to my phone. After i did that, the programm worked out of the terminal just fine